# One tap phone number in Google Calendar invite

Tags: google-calendar-api

The Google API Calendar event [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) describe how to create a Google calendar invite using conference solutions. I'm trying to put a phone number in the invite that the user can click on (from a mobile device) that will dial the number.

I'm working under the assumption that this is possible.

Since I'm not trying to connect this to a Google hangout or meet, I think I need to use `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type = "addOn"`

But is a regular phone call is considered a 3P conference provider?

```
conferenceData = {
    "entryPoints" : [
         {
            "entryPointType": "phone",
            "uri": `tel:${number},,${pin}`,
            "label": number,
            "pin": pin,
            "passcode": pin,
            "password": pin
          },
    ],
    "conferenceSolution" : {
        "key" : {
          "type" : "addOn",
         },
         "name" : number,
         "iconUri" : "",
    },
};
```

This raises a couple of questions

1. Does anyone know if this use case is supported by Google Calendar?
2. Is there another param I can set that is designed for this use case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by wanting to add a phone number? Like [this](https://imgur.com/yx2hjAz) ?

Comment: Exactly. I want to allow the user to launch the phone call (with pin) with one click from the email of the google calendar invite. Right now, using "location" I can launch the call with one click, but it doesn't dial the pin too.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it mention phone number exactly?

Comment: It looks like it's an allowed entryPointType

Answer (score 0):

First, this is possible.

I ended up getting it to work by modifying what I have above.
The docs mention that

> When creating new conference data, populate only the subset of
> {meetingCode, accessCode, passcode, password, pin} fields that match
> the terminology that the conference provider uses

So it became:

```
conferenceData = {
    "entryPoints" : [
         {
            "entryPointType": "phone",
            "uri": `tel:${number},,${pin}`,
            "label": number,
          },
    ],
    "conferenceSolution" : {
        "key" : {
          "type" : "addOn",
         },
         "name" : number,
    },
}
```